# How to get text in this code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In the below code, the code is available. Kindly check it. A text is not printing.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_1")).sendKeys("surya4u");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_3")).sendKeys("surnamerajesh4");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_6")).sendKeys("surya4u@yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_9")).sendKeys("surya4u@yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).sendKeys("surya4u");
Select date = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day")));
date.selectByValue("24");
Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
month.selectByValue("9");
Select year = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));
year.selectByValue("1987");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#u_0_f")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_j")).click();
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='reg_error_inner']"));
System.out.println(text.getText());
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the error message to be visible.  I added a wait and updated your selector for the error text.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_1")).sendKeys("surya4u");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_3")).sendKeys("surnamerajesh4");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_6")).sendKeys("surya4u@yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_9")).sendKeys("surya4u@yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).sendKeys("surya4u");
Select date = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day")));
date.selectByValue("24");
Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
month.selectByValue("9");
Select year = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));
year.selectByValue("1987");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#u_0_f")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_j")).click();
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.id("reg_error_inner"));

// Wait for text to be visible
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(text));

System.out.println(text.getText());
driver.close();
```